# how to access redirectAttributes.addFalshAttributed value in hbs(handlebars) file

Tags: spring, spring-boot

```
@PostMapping("/upload") // //new annotation since 4.3
public String singleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                               RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    if (file.isEmpty()) {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Please select a file to upload");
        return "redirect:uploadStatus";
    }
    try {
        // Get the file and save it somewhere
        byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
        Path path = Paths.get(UPLOADED_FOLDER + file.getOriginalFilename());
        Files.write(path, bytes);

        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
                "You successfully uploaded '" + file.getOriginalFilename() + "'");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "redirect:/uploadStatus";
}
```

how to access message value of above code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<body>

<h1>Spring Boot - Upload Status</h1>


<h2>{{message}}</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

The above code can't access message value.  how to access in handlebars file.
I want to show string of message variable.

Answer (score 0):

Not any special treatment for flash attribute. It is same like model attribute with redirection.

Change this

```
<h2>{{message}}</h2>
```

to

```
<h2>${message}</h2>
```

Comment: It does not work well... result of code is                                                                 
Spring Boot - Upload Status
${message}              <- not work

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the $ or # symbol depends on how you want to resolve your expression. Use something like below:

```
<h2 th:text="${message}"><h2>
```

Please check the standard expression syntax section [standarddialect5minutes](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standarddialect5minutes.html)

Comment: Your uploadStatus redirect is routed through controller method or direct?

Answer (score 0):

Your [handlebars](https://jknack.github.io/handlebars.java/gettingStarted.html) variable reference in your html is actually correct as-is.

If your redirect is routed through the controller (as in, if your GET method for `updateStatus` is defined in your controller), then you may need to follow what I described in an answer I gave to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63077052/5012320). Basically, when using `RedirectAttributes` in a PRG situation, all you need to do is:

1. Include `RedirectAttributes` as parameter to the POST method signature
2. Set the attribute you want via `addFlashAttribute` within the POST method
3. Include a @ModelAttribute annotated parameter in the GET method signature which references the flash attribute

You did not post your `updateStatus` GET method code so I cannot see what you are doing in it, but if you are doing anything like trying to set that attribute on the model directly that will inadvertently cause the flash attribute to be overwritten.

If I had to guess, I would say the problem is that you are missing the @ModelAttribute annotated parameter within the GET method signature.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a mustache, then
`{{ message }}`    <- I thinks it's not a problem.

now try

```
{{#msg}}
            {{msg}}
    {{/msg}}
```

'#' and '/' annotes starting and end point. For me, without it, error occured saying
there's no method for message.