# Spring boot redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute not preserving the value in the immediate redirect

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redirect

I have a controller class which implements GET-POST-GET redirect pattern. I have tried to use addFlashAttribute in the POST request and redirecting to GET but the model object in GET does not contain the set value. Here is my code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/eg")
public class Example extends AbstractBaseController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/account", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String renderFavouriteView(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        ExtendedModelMap modelMap,
        @ModelAttribute("result") String postResult) {


    modelMap.addAttribute("result", postResult); //postResult is empty

    return "account.ftl";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/account", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleFavouriteView(
        AccountForm accountForm,
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        ExtendedModelMap modelMap,
        RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

    ServiceResult serviceResult = myAccountService.createAccount(accountForm);

    if (!serviceResult.isSuccess()) {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("result", "Done");
    } else {

        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("result", "Failed");
    }

    Map<String,?> m = redirectAttributes.getFlashAttributes(); // present here.

    return "redirect:/eg/account";
}
```

}

Please let me know, if I am missing something here.

Answer (score 1):

When using `RedirectAttributes` in a PRG situation, all you need to do is:

1. Include `RedirectAttributes` as parameter to the POST method signature
2. Set the attribute you want via `addFlashAttribute` within the POST method
3. Include a @ModelAttribute annotated parameter in the GET method signature which references the flash attribute

So you really do not need this line from the POST method:

```
Map<String,?> m = redirectAttributes.getFlashAttributes(); // present here.
```

**But I think your actual problem is you are unintentionally overwriting the model attribute in the GET method with the following line**:

```
modelMap.addAttribute("result", postResult); //postResult is empty
```

Flash attributes are already automatically added to the model during the redirection, so above line is actually overwriting it. **If you remove that line it should work as intended.**